# Rotate a cube with my method

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a class with this method

rotire.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

namespace WpfApplication3
{
    class rotire:MonoBehaviour
    {
        float speed = 10f;
        public void rotiree()
        {
            transform.Rotate(new Vector3(15,40,45)*speed,Time.deltaTime);
        }

    }
```

}

I want use this method  to rotate my cube made in XAML.

Unfortunately it not work and I think my code is incorectly.

Please, can someone help me whit an ideea, what i should write.

Window1,cs

```
 private void Window_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        rotire rot = new rotire();
        rot.rotiree();
        mycube.Transform = rot;
    }
```

I belive the last line of code is wrong, because i receive this error

```
"Cannot implicitly convert type 'WpfApplication3.rotire' to 'System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Transform3D'"
```

Answer (score 1):

That last line should be the following:

```
mycube.Transform = rot.transform;
```

Comment: another error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.Transform' to 'System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Transform3D"

Comment: That's because Unity transforms are not the same thing as WPF transforms. They are from completely different systems and are different classes. Googling how to convert between them did not result in anything, so maybe you should ask another question here about specifically that. Or, alternatively, you could not use Unity and only use WPF in your project.

Comment: you mean to search or ask how to Covert WPF (Transform) to Unity (Transform)?